# StackOverflow Technology Stack

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

How is stackoverflow able to offer such a smooth user experience for such a large userbase?  I would love to know what its technology stack is including OS/Webserver/Database/Programming Language and optimization strategies (e.g. memcache).

Comment: This is a question for [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: No, it's a question for meta, but it's already been asked there a zillion times: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 1):

[An old blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) has some details.